# hasOneThrough with pivot table laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables

```
mysql> describe records;
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| event_school_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| athlete_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| year            | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| place           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at      | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe event_school;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| event_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| school_id  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| notes      | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe events;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From my Record Eloquent model, how can I get an **event** from a record. It needs to go though event_school pivot table; but I don't have a model for EventSchool. Do I need to make one? Is there a way to do that without EventSchool model?

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class EventSchool extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $table = 'event_school';

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
    }

    public function school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }

}
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Record extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function athlete()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Athlete');
    }

    function event_school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\EventSchool','event_school_id');
    }

    function event()
    {
        //What can I put here to complete method

        //right now have to do \App\Record::find(1)->event_school->event

        //Want to do \App\Record::find(1)->event
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is output from one of the answers

```
>>> \App\Record::find(3)->event_school->event
=> App\Event {#3035
     id: 1,
     name: "100 Meter",
     category_id: 1,
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     deleted_at: null,
   }
>>> \App\Record::find(3)->event
=> null
```

Comment: Can you use another relationship to get this? E.g. record->athlete->school->event_school? Pivot tables in Laravel are meant to be largely transparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time I got into this situation I end up creating a model for the pivot table. An additional benefit of doing this, is that you can access directly to that table without bringing the other end of the relationship.

You already have additional information to the foreign keys (`notes`). If you have a `School` and need the `notes` from an `Event`, but you DON'T need the `Event`, you can do that if the pivot table has a model.
Of course you could do it with a `join` without the need of a model.

The key here is to extend from [`Pivot`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) instead of `Model`. One of the things it does is to get the table name as singular. But you can't use `SoftDeletes` (do you really need it? It doesn't makes much sense)

> Note: Pivot models may not use the SoftDeletes trait. If you need to soft delete pivot records consider converting your pivot model to an actual Eloquent model.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class EventSchool extends Pivot
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }

    public function school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(School::class);
    }
}
```

Now, [hasOneThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) is the inverse of what you need. You need something like `belongsToThrough`, but it doesn't exists. What you could use is an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Record extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function athlete()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Athlete::class);
    }

    function eventSchool()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EventSchool::class);
    }

    function getEventAttribute()
    {
        return $this->eventSchool->event;
    }
}
```

Doing `\App\Record::find(1)->event` will do exactly what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 2):

I create a fresh install of laravel on my computer, set up the models and relations according to the information that you provide, and the simplest solution i came up with is this one:

```php
public function event()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Event::class, EventSchool::class,
        'event_id', 'id', 'id', 'event_id'
    );
}
```

This is the test that i made:

```php
// Within some controller:
$record = Record::find(2);
dd($record->event);
```

And this is the result, which i think is the result you are looking for:

```php
Event {#303 ▼
  #connection: "pgsql"
  #table: "events"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Event 2"
    "category_id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2019-09-16 03:15:07"
    "updated_at" => "2019-09-16 03:15:07"
    "laravel_through_key" => 2
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost works. For record id 3 it returns null.  I think somethign is wrong with how this is being setup with keys

>>> \App\Record::find(3)->event_school->event
=> App\Event {#3035
     id: 1,
     name: "100 Meter",
     category_id: 1,
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     deleted_at: null,
   }
>>> \App\Record::find(3)->event
=> null

Comment: I updated question with the output of laravel tinker

Comment: Any differences in your database with the record id 3 and the records where the relationship works?

Comment: I think you are doing somethin wrong. I added more events, event_schools and records to my database, and this relation works pretty well.

Comment: Or maybe i made something wrong xD. Try with this relation: `return $this->hasOneThrough(Event::class, EventSchool::class, 'event_id', 'id', 'id','id')`

Comment: still no luck. Here is database with data https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfw9k3msph7695k/track_and_field.sql?dl=0

Comment: @ChrisMuench I don't think [hasOneThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) is the correct relationship. As you can see in the example, `history` have `user_id`, `users` have `supplier_id` and `suppliers` doesn't have any. This case is exactly the opposite, `event` doesn't have `event_school_id` and `event_school` doesn't have `record_id`. `records` have `event_school_id` and `event_school` have `event_id`. That's why I suggest to use an accessor.